# What is a Resilient Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a ***Resilient Word™***.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

$$
% set Title text. (spaces around the text ARE important; do not remove.)
% increase Pad value only if your entries are longer than the title bar.
%
\def\Pad{\P{0.0}}  \def\Title{\textbf{ Resilient }}
%
\def\S#1#2{\Space{#1}{20px}{#2px}}\def\P#1{\V{#1em}}\def\V#1{\S{#1}{9}}
\def\T{\Title\textbf{Words}^{\;\!™}\Pad}\def\NT{\Pad\textbf{Not}\T\ }\displaystyle
\smash{\lower{29px}\bbox[yellow]{\phantom{\rlap{rubio.2019.05.15}\S{6px}{0}
\begin{array}{cc}\Pad\T&\NT\\\end{array}}}}\atop\def\V#1{\S{#1}{5}}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\Pad\T&\NT\\\hline
%
\text{  PRESENT         }&\text{        GIFT            }\\ \hline
\text{  SUSPECT         }&\text{        SUSPICIOUS      }\\ \hline
\text{  INVALID         }&\text{        VALID           }\\ \hline
\text{  ADDRESS         }&\text{        LOCATION        }\\ \hline
\text{  CONTENT         }&\text{        ITEM            }\\ \hline
\text{  PROJECT         }&\text{        REPOSITORY      }\\ \hline
\text{  INSERT          }&\text{        DELETE          }\\ \hline
\text{  OBJECT          }&\text{        CLASS           }\\ \hline
\text{  RECORD          }&\text{        COMPUTER        }\\ \hline
\text{  COMPOUND        }&\text{        AMALGAM         }\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Error 405: Method Not Allowed
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Resilient Word™ without relying on the other words.
These are not the only examples of Resilient Words™; many more exist.

**What is the special rule for a Resilient Word™?**

Comment: It's unfortunate that the server chose to reject the call for the CSV version... (*a Resilient response, indeed*).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> A resilient word has common pronunciations with different syllables stressed in different parts of speech. It's called resilient because it can survive being dragged into a different part of speech: it adapts thereto by changing its pronunciation.

Comment: Wow, good find! But then how is "address" Resilient? (Maybe an accent thing?) And why is the CSV version "not allowed"?

Comment: @ran "address" fits the pattern in some dialects. Dunno about the CSV.

Comment: Gah, rats - must have started writing up only moments before you posted!! Well done :) Glad I didn't continue to explain _all_ the words - I'd have regretted that even more!

Comment: @Randal'Thor Think US first-syllable pronunciation for the noun...

Comment: Isn't it invalid*ate* though?

Comment: I wonder if the reason there's no CSV is because it wouldn't help to identify the answer, since the property is related to pronunciation, not spelling.

Comment: @Sandra, "Invalid" is also a rarely-used, often offensive, term for a disabled person, which is pronounced very differently from "invalid data". See https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/invalid, Etymology 2. Anecdotally, the only place I've seen it used these days is in the phrase "invalid carriage" as a catch-all term for various configurations of electric wheelchairs and mobility scooters.

Comment: Oh, I gotcha, I thought they also had to switch word class from noun to verb so I didn't even think to look for other [elided because puzzle spoiler] within the same word class. Thanx

Comment: I think that's a different word class, just not noun and verb: invalid as 'not valid' is an adjective, but the use ymbirtt refers to is a noun.

Comment: @F1Krazy Because you **s**eparate the **v**alues of syllables with hyphens, and not with **c**ommas?

Comment: @Randal'Thor trying not to give too much away, to my ear it's the difference between talking to a crowd and mailing a letter.

Comment: @senderle I pronounce it the same in both of those contexts.

Comment: @Randal'Thor yeah I suspect that might be true for a few of these depending on dialect.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I suspect that [the server returned a Resilient response](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92688/what-is-a-resilient-word#comment266304_92688) when fetching the CSV version.

Answer (score 3):

A Resilient Word is:

> A word which can mean different things when different syllables are stressed.

For example:

> 'Present' could be pronounced PRES-ent (as in a gift) or pres-ENT (meaning to give a presentation).
>
>  Similarly, 'suspect' could be either a 'SUS-pect' (in a police investigation) or to 'su-SPECT' something (when you think something is wrong).

As for the name:

> 'Resilient' doesn't follow the rule, but by definition something resilient can withstand many situations - like changing which syllable is stressed...